# Issue with PHP parssing SOAP response

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

I've created the following PHP script to display a list of properties from a SOAP API we use.

The script works fine when we have more than one property being advertised but shows nothing when we only have one property being advertised.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong or a simple check that would fix the problem?

My code is:

```
$wsdl = "http://portal.letmc.com/PropertySearchService.asmx?WSDL";

$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array ("trace"=>1, "exceptions"=>0));

$strClientID = "{xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx}";
$strBranchID = "{xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx}";                         
$nMaxResults = "5";
$nRentMinimum = 100;
$nRentMaximum = 900;
$nMaximumTenants = 5;                           

$parameters = array(    "strClientID"=>$strClientID, 
                    "strBranchID"=>$strBranchID, 
                    "nMaxResults"=>$nMaxResults,
                    "nRentMinimum"=>$nRentMinimum,
                    "nRentMaximum"=>$nRentMaximum,
                    "nMaximumTenants"=>$nMaximumTenants
                );                          

 $values = $client->SearchProperties($parameters);


if($values != '')
{
echo "<table>";
        echo '<tr>
                <th>Apartment</th>
                <th class="center">Bedrooms</th>
                <th>Rent</th>
                <th>Description</th>
            </tr>';

    foreach ($values->SearchPropertiesResult->PropertyInfo as $message)
    {
        $address = $message->Address1;
        $rooms = $message->MaxTenants;
        $rent = $message->Rent;
        $description = $message->Description;

        echo '<tr>';        
        echo '<td>'. $address .'</td>
                  <td class="center">'. $rooms .'</td>
              <td>'. $rent .'</td>
              <td>'. $description .'</td>';
        echo '</tr>';

    }
    echo '</table>'; 
}

else 
{
echo '<p><strong>Sorry, we have no properties available.</strong></p> <p>Please register your details on the right and we will let you know as soon as an apartment comes available.</p>';  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is common on .NET web services. If there is more than one result, then it's an array, but if there's only one result, instead of an array with one result, you get the result itself in `PropertyInfo`.

The solution is to test if it's an array, and if it isn't, then move the object into an array, so that you can work with it in the same way, for both single results and arrays of results.

Add this code after your `SearchProperties()` call, and before the foreach.

```
if(!is_array($values->SearchPropertiesResult->PropertyInfo))
{
    $values->SearchPropertiesResult->PropertyInfo = array($values->SearchPropertiesResult->PropertyInfo);
}
```

After this, `$values->SearchPropertiesResult->PropertyInfo` is now an array, regardless of it having only a single property or multiple. So your foreach will work.

Comment: Worked a treat - Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can configure the PHP SoapClient to not convert single element arrays into the element itself. Use the "features" key in the option parameter and set it to `SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS` like this:

```
$options = array('features' => SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS);
$client = new SoapClient("wsdl", $options);
```

That way you do not have to check for single elements or arrays, but can simply assume there is an array.